# Ajuda com apk android studio

Tags: android-studio

Estou compilando a minha aplicação no android studio e não da erro nenhum. no simulador eu vejo a aplicação normalmente. quando vou na pasta onde a aplicação está C:\Users\Ronaldo\Desktop\Android\Teste\app\build\outputs\apk. a aplicação foi gerada e mas não passa de 500K e a mesma não roda no celular.  anteriormente esta aplicação dava em torno de 2,6650 k.  alguem sabe o que pode ser? isto ocorreu depois que meu pc travou

Answer (score 1):

Esse apk que Android Studio gera é uma versão apenas que ele usa para instalar no seu emulador e celular, se estiver rodando direto nele, mas para gerar uma versão realmente instalável você precisa usar o comando Menu: Build=>Build APK.

E isso foi uma alteração que o Android Studio implementou na versão 2.3.

Comment: entendi Gabriel, porque anteriormente eu colocava direto do do apk da pasta e funcionava, vou testar

Comment: eu demorei um pouco para descobrir, eu passava o apk para meus técnicos e eles relatavam erro, até que eu vi que o apk ficava com tamanho infinitamente menor eu resolvi testar e descobri.

Comment: Gabriel, funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado

Comment: De nada, marca como resolvida e pontua lá então :D